# What are the limitations if my app depends upon dynamic realm only?

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I want to build an app having dynamic database. In Realm documentation it is mentioned that

> Dynamic Realms are opened using the same configuration you use for the conventional Realms, but they ignore any schema, migration, and schema version.

What does this mean "they ignore any schema, migration, and schema version". Is it okay to build tables and fields dynamically? What are the limitation of dynamic realm?

Comment: Android, right?

Comment: currently android..

Comment: No real limitation that I know of, just know that Realm **does** have a schema and it might be tricky to listen for changes in results that belong to classes that don't exist yet.

Comment: Are you talking about the Realm with the synchronization features to other devices/server? or just Realm database locally?

Comment: with synchronization feature

Comment: in Realm Sync only additive changes are allowed. As mentioned, you should be careful when querying/updating the schema to use existing Table/field. You can use `realm.getSchema().contains(className)` to check for a table & `RealmObjectSchema.hasField` to check for a field